# An issue when trying to change the bubble color in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

For the following plot:

[image]

I would like to change the color of the bubbles to a more bright and clear colors than the black. For that, I've written the following R script:

```
ggplot(counts, aes(x=RW, y=GA, size=Freq, color=Freq)) + geom_point(alpha=0.8) +
    scale_size(range = c(1, 16), name="Freq %") +
    theme(text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16)) + xlab("Covered by RW") + ylab("Covered by MOSA")
```

To change the color, I added this line `scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2")` but this gives me the error `Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale`

Do you have any idea how to change the color? Also, what should I do to remove the legend in the top?

Comment: The Brewer scales are discrete. If you have a continuous variable (seems like you do, but without your data that's just a guess), you need a continuous scale

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Use scale_colour_distiller to apply palette to continuous and guides to turn off the size legendL

```
counts=data.frame(RW=runif(20),GA=runif(20),Freq=runif(20))

ggplot(counts, aes(x=RW, y=GA, size=Freq, color=Freq)) + geom_point(alpha=0.8) +
    scale_size(range = c(1, 16), name="Freq %") +
    theme(text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16)) + xlab("Covered by RW") + ylab("Covered by MOSA")+
    scale_colour_distiller(palette="Dark2")+
    guides(color=FALSE,shape=guide_legend())
```

[image]